# How to pipeline/chained regex expressions

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have to extract the measure units and quantities from String texts. Like in this samples:

```
Original String // result:

abc1mgabc // extract 1 and mg separately
abc100mlabc //100 and ml
abc256kgabc //256 and kg
```

Until now in a first moment I use this regular expression:

```
(?i)\d{1,5}(mg|g|gr|kg|ml|l)
```

to extract Quantity and Unit and store into `quant_unit` String.

after that, I apply over `quant_unit` this two regular expressions: `\d` and `(?i)(mg|g|gr|kg|ml|l)` to extract respectively "quantity" and "measure unit".

But I think it must have a way to extract it separately by applying just a regular expression (for each item to extract) over the original string?

I though use some kind like:

original_string -> applyRegex (to extract measure and unit) -> applyRegex2 (to extract measure or unit from that).

Using its own regular expression or the Pattern class from Java.

I'm create a enum to easy access of Patterns:

```
public enum Patterns {

    //the expression is: (?i)\d{1,5}(mg|g|gr|kg|ml|l)
    QUANTITY_UNIT("(?i)\\d{1,5}(" + MeasureUnit.getRegex() + ")"),
    QUANTITY("\\d"),
    UNIT("(?i)(" + MeasureUnit.getRegex() + ")");

    private Pattern pattern;

    Patterns(String patternString) {
        System.out.println(patternString);
        pattern = pattern.compile(patternString);
    }

    public Pattern getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }

    public Matcher getMatcher(CharSequence input) {
        return getPattern().matcher(input);
    }

    public String findGroup(CharSequence input) {
        Matcher matcher = getMatcher(input);
        matcher.find();
        return matcher.group();

    }
```

And the Unit Test for the desired behaviour:

```
public class PatternsTest {

@Test
public void quantityUnit() {
    String testString = "abc1kgabc1l";
    String fg = Patterns.QUANTITY_UNIT.findGroup(testString);
    Assert.assertEquals("1KG", fg);
}


@Test
public void quantity() {
    String testString = "abc1kgabc1l";
    String fg = Patterns.QUANTITY.findGroup(testString);
    Assert.assertEquals("1", fg);
}


@Test
public void unity() {
    String testString = "abc1kgabc1l";
    String fg = Patterns.UNIT.findGroup(testString);
    Assert.assertEquals("kg", fg);
}

}
```

---

### EDIT

I made some refactoring based on commentaries e answers, now it works fine:

```
public enum Patterns {

    QUANTITY_UNIT("(?i)([0-9]+)(" + MeasureUnit.getRegex() + ")");

    private Pattern pattern;

    Patterns(String patternString) {
        pattern = pattern.compile(patternString);
    }

    public Pattern getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }

    public Matcher getMatcher(CharSequence input) {
        return getPattern().matcher(input);
    }

    public String getQuantity(CharSequence input) {
        final int group_idx = 1;

        Matcher matcher = getMatcher(input);
        boolean found = matcher.find();
        return found ? toLower(matcher.group(group_idx)) : "";
    }

    private String toLower(String input) {
        return input.toLowerCase();
    }

    public String getUnity(CharSequence input) {
        final int group_idx = 2;

        Matcher matcher = getMatcher(input);
        boolean found = matcher.find();
        return found ? toLower(matcher.group(group_idx)) : "";
    }
}
```

---

### the test:

```
public class MeasureUnityTest {


    @Test
    public void quantity() {
        String testString = "abc1kgabc1l";
        String fg = QUANTITY_UNIT.getQuantity(testString);
        Assert.assertEquals("1", fg);
    }


    @Test
    public void unity() {
        String testString = "abc1kgabc1l";
        String fg = QUANTITY_UNIT.getUnity(testString);
        Assert.assertEquals("kg", fg);
    }

    @Test
    public void unityUpperCase() {
        String testString = "abc1KGabc1l";
        String fg = QUANTITY_UNIT.getUnity(testString);
        Assert.assertEquals("kg", fg);
    }


    @Test
    public void unityNoOccurrence() {
        String testString = "fasfasfasfaf";
        String fg = QUANTITY_UNIT.getQuantity(testString);
        Assert.assertEquals("", fg);
    }

    @Test
    public void unityEmptyString() {
        String testString = "";
        String fg = QUANTITY_UNIT.getQuantity(testString);
        Assert.assertEquals("", fg);
    }

    /* If more than one matches, return the first*/
    @Test
    public void unityMoreThanOne() {
        String testString = "abc5mlabc5kg";
        String fg = QUANTITY_UNIT.getUnity(testString);
        Assert.assertEquals("ml", fg);
    }

    /* If more than one matches, return the first*/
    @Test
    public void quantityMoreThanOne() {
        String testString = "abcm5mlabc1kg";
        String fg = QUANTITY_UNIT.getQuantity(testString);
        Assert.assertEquals("5", fg);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalizing all the comments, you can use something similar to this ([IDEONE link](http://ideone.com/PvLhdH)):

```
String[] tests = { "abc1mgabc","abc100mlabc","abc256kgabc"};
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?i)([0-9]+)(gr|kg|mg|ml|g|l)");
for (String s: tests) {
    Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("QNTY: " + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("UNIT:" + matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
QNTY: 1
UNIT:mg
QNTY: 100
UNIT:ml
QNTY: 256
UNIT:kg
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/PvLhdH)

Main points:

- You can just use 2 capturing groups and capture both entities with 1 regex.
- Make sure the longest alternatives come first in the alternation since the first one found is chosen in the Java regex (that does not comply with the POSIX standard for alternation where the longest one found is chosen).
- If you are not sure how big the numbers can be, it is enough to use the `+` quantifier (one or more occurrences) rather than the limiting `{1,5}` that will only match 1 to 5 occurrences.